# Docker not saving a file created using python - Flask application

Tags: docker, flask

I created a Flask Application. This application receives a XML from a url and saves it:

```
  response = requests.get(base_url)
  with open('currencies.xml', 'wb') as file:
      file.write(response.content)
```

When I run the application without Docker, the file `currencies.xml` is correctly created inside my app folder.
However, this behaviour does not occur when I use docker.

In docker I run the following commands:

```
docker build -t my-api-docker:latest .
docker run -p 5000:5000 my-api-docker ~/Desktop/myApiDocker # This is where I want the file to be saved: inside the main Flask folder
```

When I run the second command, I get:

> > docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/Users/name/Desktop/myApiDocker\": stat /Users/name/Desktop/myApiDocker: no such file or directory": unknown.
> >     ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled

**But** If I run:

```
docker build -t my-api-docker:latest .
docker run -p 5000:5000 my-api-docker # Without specifying the PATH
```

I can access the website (but it is pretty useless without the file `currencies.xml`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 my-api-docker ~/Desktop/myApiDocker
```

Docker interprets everything after the image name (`my-api-docker`) as the command to run.  It runs `/Users/name/Desktop/myApiDocker` as a command, *instead of* what you have as the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, and when that path doesn't exist in the container, you get the error you see.

It's a little unlikely you'll be able to pass this path to your `flask run` command as a command-line argument.  A typical way of dealing with this is by using an environment variable instead.  In your code,

```py
download_dir = os.environ.get('DOWNLOAD_DIR', '.')
currencies_xml = os.path.join(download_dir, 'currencies.xml')
with open(currencies_xml, 'wb') as file:
  ...
```

Then when you start your container, you can pass that as an environment variable with the `docker run -e` option.  Note that this names a path inside the container; there's no particular need for this to match the path on the host.

```
docker run \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  -e DOWNLOAD_DIR=/data \
  -v $HOME/Desktop/myApiDocker:/data \
  my-api-docker
```

It's also fairly common to put an `ENV` statement in your Dockerfile or otherwise pick a fixed path for this, and just specify that your image's interface is that it will download the file into whatever is mounted on `/data`.